# NULL folder inside public folder on CI 4 project

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

What is NULL folder inside public folder in my CI 4 project? seems like session cookies. How to set folder name so not appear as NULL, Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you opted for the Driver `FileHandler` of Codeigniter 4 which stores session in files. In order to work properly you also need to give him a session save path.
Session configs are driven in the `.env` file and/or in `app/Config/App.php`.

**Example of the config in App.php file with a session save path** :

```
public $sessionDriver            = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler';
public $sessionCookieName        = 'ci_session';
public $sessionExpiration        = 28000; // 8h
public $sessionSavePath          = 'hello/world';
public $sessionMatchIP           = false;
public $sessionTimeToUpdate      = 300;
public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = true;
```

**Watch out :**
*It currently looks like that setting config in both files for the FileHandler driver is a bad idea. Setting it in `App.php` file seems a better option since it allows you to use multiple directories like `dir1/dir2/my_session` where this syntax catch an error in the `.env` file. But still be aware that the .env config ALWAYS takes over the one set in App.php*

Comment: Hi Vilar, i put public $sessionSavePath          = 'SESSION' in App.php; but session still point to NULL folder. i have created SESSION folder inside public folder. Can u help?

Comment: Watch your .env file then check that app.sessionDriver is either commented out or equals to 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler' and that app.sessionSavePath is commented out or equals to 'SESSION'.
If it doesn't work please post both files (only the part about session of course) in your question.

Comment: U're right. i forgot commented out that part in my .env. Thank you!